# Android DataBinding fails to update views after fragment resumes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-databinding

I have one activity with only a `FragmentContainerView`, who's fragment is initiated right in the XML of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/xlink_light_blue">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:name="com.x.y.MainFragment" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainFragment` uses a view model and view binding, which is created like so:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

...and in `onCreateView` I initiate this binding and create observers for the view model:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root
    viewModel.exampleViewShown.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { exampleViewShown ->
        binding.exampleView.visibility = if (exampleViewShown) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE
    }
    return root
}
```

Whereas `exampleViewShown` is defined in the view model as:

```
val exampleViewShown = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = false }
```

The view model then changes the value of `exampleViewShown` multiple times a second, which all works at first. If the device then goes to sleep for roughly over 10 seconds and wakes up, the view is no longer updated.

Debugging shows that neither `binding` nor `exampleView` are null and the changes from the view model are still received by the fragment (the block from `observe` is still called).

I have also monitored if the fragment gets recreated, but `onCreateView` is never called a second time, neither are `onDestroyView` (and so on) called on the original fragment.

What could be the cause for the view no longer updating?

Comment: Layout provided doesn't contain `exampleView`